# How to retrive the parameters in URL + laravel

Tags: json, laravel

for web services , how to retrieve the data json format using Laravel, can anybody help

```
https://test.com/admin/users/apiLogin?Login={"email":test@test.com,"pwd":testing}

in Controller

  public function apiLogin(Request $request)
    {

        //$data = $request->json()->all();

        $data=json_decode($request['Login']);

        echo $data['email'];
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "testsetet";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: the data should be url encoded. it would however be better to put this data in a post request since url parameters are rather insecure and this could thus expose passwords!

Comment: `passwords` shouldn't be passed as a GET parameters. Also it's probably better for clients to hash the passwords before sending it to apis(?).

Answer (score 0):

**To get the URL parameter use this:**

```
$login = $request->input('login'); // or $request['Login']
```

The goal is to turn `login` (which is a string) into appropriate JSON format so that you can use json_decode.

**I'll break it down in steps:**

1. Remove all `\n` characters:

   `$login = str_replace('\n', '', $login);`
2. Remove last comma

   `$login = rtrim($login, ',');`
3. Add brackets

   `$login = "[" . trim($login) . "]";`
4. Turn it into a PHP array:

   `$json = json_decode($login, true);`

Comment: Isn't `{"email":test@test.com,"pwd":testing}` valid json whatsoever?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your url parameter 'Login' isn't properly formatted json.  I would revisit your front-end code persisting this data and ensure it is formatting properly.  True json should look like:

```
{"email":"test@test.com","pwd":"testing"}
```

As a BIG aside, never persist passwords in the URL.  It is dangerously foolish.  Use a POST request to do this.  On the plus side, the back-end code will be virtually the same with your json_decode() logic.